# C++: Is cast from const vector<Derived*> to const vector<Base*> safe?

Tags: c++, casting

Derived extends Base.

I have a `vector<Derived*>`.

I need to call a function with the signature `MyFunc(const vector<Base*>&)`

Is the following code safe (assuming there is no const_cast)?

```
vector<Derived*> DerivedVec;
vector<Base*>& BaseVec = *reinterpret_cast<vector<Base*>*>(&DerivedVec);
MyFunc(BaseVec);
```

Because MyFunc can't add elements to the vector, the vector should always be valid?

**I do not want to copy the vector for performance reason.**

Comment: No it is not valid, you have to copy vector or better have `std::vector<Base*>` from the beginning

Comment: @Rakete1111 Are you implying that all reinterpret_cast are unsafe? That isn't true. For example, reinterpret_cast from `int` to `unsigned int` is safe.

Comment: @RainingChain No. In fact, you're right. I meant that `reinterpret_cast` with *pointers* is generally unsafe when you cast between two different pointer types.